# I need to show each fruit a and b in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, redux

- I have array of fruits, in that I need to show each fruit a and b in the browser.
- I am using map method to iterate the array but not sure how to show it in the browser.
- can you tell me how to achieve using js.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below.

```js
function sampleFunction() {
  let fruits = ["a", "b"];

  fruits.map(item => {
    console.log("item--->", item);
    return item;
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #1d2126;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello, World</h1>

<button onclick=sampleFunction()>test</button>
```

Comment: You need to decide where you want this information to appear on your page. When this is settled you can start thinking how actually to make it work.

Comment: you need to create an html tag for the fruits, than give it an id, and after that use js to make the html element inner text to be the fruits

Comment: @Yahli hey can you update in my code snippet so confusing :(

Comment: @PM77-1 hey I need to show it in the browser in any part.... can you update in my code snippet so confusing :(

Comment: why are you using redux ?

Answer (score 0):

changed the code. that should work if I understood what you wanted correctly.

edit: I didnt understood why you need the mapping, so unless you want it to something else you should remove it.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: #1d2126;
        color: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, World</h1>
    <p id="fruits"></p>
    <button onclick= sampleFunction()
            
            
            >test</button>
    
    <script>
      
      function sampleFunction(){
  
  let fruits =["a", "b"];
  
  fruits.map( item =>{
    
    console.log("item--->", item);
    
    return item;
  
  });

 var fruitsElement = document.getElementById('fruits');
 for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){
       fruitsElement.innerHTML += fruits[i];
 }
}

    
    
    </script>
    
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: instaed of for loop, can you use map method

Comment: @user12287673 first of all its less efficient, second you dont need a for loop either